# Problem when sending jsonArray using socket.io Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, sockets, socket.io

When I send my JSONArray object through socket like this:

```
val json = JSONArray()
....
socket?.emit(EVENT, json)
```

server gets my message as array within array, like:

```
[ [ { lat: 31.476369999999996, long: 74.26562} ], 'Function0<kotlin.Unit>' ]
```

I want to send only this:

```
[ { lat: 31.476369999999996, long: 74.26562} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code to send json array using custom arraylist

```
var obj: JSONObject? = null
        val jsonArrayLatLng = JSONArray()
    for (i in 0 until list!!.size) {
            obj = JSONObject()
            try {
                obj.put("lat", list.get(i).lat)
                obj.put("long", list.get(i).lng)
                
            } catch (e: JSONException) { 
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            jsonArrayLatLng.put(obj)
        }
val jsonObject = JSONObject()
jsonObject.put("list_key_name_here", jsonArrayLatLng)
socket?.emit(EVENT, jsonObject)
```

Comment: but this will add the list to "list_key_name_here", i just need to send an array, without a key.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
socket?.emit(EVENT, jsonArray.toTypedArray())
```